# Composition of binary quadratic forms as matrix operations

Tags: number-theory, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

It is easy to see that any binary quadratic form $a^2 + 2bxy + cy^2$ is the same as $XAX^T$ where $X = [x, y]$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{bmatrix}.$

The composition of two binary quadratic forms $f(x,y)$ and $g(z,w)$ is a form $F(s(x,y,z,w),t(x,y,z,w)) = f(x,y)g(z,w)$ where $s = pxz+qxw+ryz+syw$ and similarly for $t$  Is there any way to see this as a matrix operation?

Edit: Corrected a mistake.

Comment: Who says that's what a composition is?

Comment: @WillJagy I changed a bit in the question. Is that you meant or am I missing something else?

Comment: What book are you reading? I know binary quadratic forms very, very well. So far you have not given me any reason to answer. What do you already know about this, and what have you tried?

Comment: @WillJagy I am going through "Primes of the form x^2 + ny^2". Whatever operation it is has to be commutative, have det equal to f,g. It also has to essentially have 4 "forms" since there are 4 possible compositions. Given these restrictions, I am not really sure what operations work.

Comment: See Dirichlet composition on page 49

Answer (score 3):

For a definition of composition using matrices, see H. [Brandt](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0150&DMDID=DMDLOG_0004), Komposition der binaeren quadratischen Formen relativ einer Grundform, J. Reine Angew. Math. 150 (1919), 1-46.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know any German and cannot really locate anything like what I am looking for. Can you maybe briefly describe the idea, I think I have a decent idea of how to make it work anyway.

Comment: I have tried at least twice to work through Brandt's treatment. I guess that the matrix point of view is not really helpful here. If you want to learn composition, you're better off with Bhargava's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Every matrix has corresponding linear transformation...
So, $f,g$ have linear transformation respectively and let matrices be  $[f]$ and $[g]$..

Now the composition $f\circ g$ is just the product of the matrices $[f].[g]$.

Hope will help...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean...F has the same det as f and g so it can't be that simple.

Comment: @gloom: I think you misunderstood the word composition here. It is not the composition of binary quadratic forms as functions from, say $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This wouldn't be defined. It is the composition of binary quadratic forms as first defined by Gauss.